# Storing an array to be accessible from multiple Parse apps

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have an app installed in a couple of buildings which manages employees coming and going. Each app is a separate Parse app.

I'm trying to introduce a function which allows users to be banned. When someone is banned from building A this needs to be reflected at building B also.

How can I store an array of blocked users that can be modified and accessed by two separate Parse apps?

Comment: It sounds like it should be a single Parse app with support for multiple locations; either than or you will need to use something like a REST call to a banned user app

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it has to be multiple apps and it will likely be 5 plus buildings eventually. I'm not familiar with REST...I will look into it

Comment: How do you match the users in each different app? Cloud code can make a request from one app to the others if you set the appropriate details (this is done via an http request which is the REST part mentioned by Paulw)

Comment: At the moment the apps aren't linked at all. I was wondering about cloud code. Could I potentially just have cloud code send an updated version of the block list to an object on every app?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. When the app in building A bans a user, post that information to your webservice. Your webservice can either send notifications to the other buildings or wait till the next sync to update the ban list.